# Equation of Motion for spring-cylinder-mass system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, spring

[image]

Hello, I hope someone can help me with this question, to find the equation of motion of the disc for small angular rotations.

The mechanism comprises of a uniform circular disc of mass $m$, spring stiffness $3k$ at the highest point of the disc and spring stiffness k and damper with coefficient c attached to the center of cylinder. the disc rotates through an angle $\theta$ without slipping. Inertia about its center is $I_0 = \frac{1}{2} mr^2$, radius of cylinder = $r$, direction of motion = $x$.

I managed to work out the equation as

[image]

But i believe the correct equation should be.

$$\ddot \theta +\frac{2c}{3m}\dot\theta +\frac{26K}{3m} \theta = 0$$

Can someone tell me are there any mistakes in my concept? Much appreciated if someone can guide me along by telling me the correct concept instead of the answer itself. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Dan and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: When considering the torque around the point of contact the displacement at the center can be written as the distance to the contact point times $\theta$, $r$ at the middle but $2r$ at the top. The forces are proportional to those displacements (or its derivative). But the torque is distance times force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the book answer is correct.

The small angle approximation is not necessary : $ sin\theta $ does not appear in the analysis. $ x = r\theta $ is exact.

The motion is a rotation about the point of contact with the horizontal plane.  Using the Parallel Axes Theorem, the moment of inertia about this point is $\frac{1}{2}Mr^2 + Mr^2 = \frac{3}{2}Mr^2$.  The friction force forms a couple with the forces acting at the centre and top of the disc.

If the disc rotates anti-clockwise through angle $\theta$ then the centre moves left by $x=r\theta$ and the top moves left by $2x=2r\theta$.  The net torque on the disc causes rotational acceleration :
$-2r(3k)(2x) -r(kx+c \dot x) = \frac{3}{2}Mr^2 \ddot\theta $
$\frac{3}{2}Mr^2 \ddot\theta + cr^2 \dot\theta + 13kr^2 \theta = 0 $
$\ddot\theta + \frac{2c}{3M}\dot\theta + \frac{26k}{3M}\theta = 0$.